# Skip every nth index of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, slice

In order to do K-fold validation I would like to use slice a numpy array such that a view of the original array is made but with every nth element removed.

For example:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If `n = 4` then the result would be

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

Note: the numpy requirement is due to this being used for a machine learning assignment where the dependencies are fixed.

Comment: For the use-case of cross-validation this approach looks scary. There are some hidden assumptions then about the order of the data. I would prefer some shuffle/random_permutation based approach in general, but would also stick to the functions available in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_selection.html) as there is even more powerfull stuff like stratified sampling (if needed). Side-note: clean up your tags as ```fold``` (functional-programming) and ```k``` (programming-language) are just wrong.

Comment: I agree with sascha. In particular, take a look at the cross-validation iterators. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators

Comment: @sascha I agree that using an existing library would be better however I should have mentioned that I can only use numpy as a dependency as this is for a machine learning assignment sorry! In order to achieve randomness I am shuffling the rows using `np.random.shuffle`.

Comment: I understand. But after shuffling it does not matter if you take every 4-th or the the first N/4 values. The latter might be easier to implement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Approach #1 with `modulus`**

```
a[np.mod(np.arange(a.size),4)!=0]
```

Sample run -

```
In [255]: a
Out[255]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [256]: a[np.mod(np.arange(a.size),4)!=0]
Out[256]: array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9])
```

---

**Approach #2 with `masking` : Requirement as a `view`**

Considering the views requirement, if the idea is to save on memory, we could store the equivalent boolean array that would occupy `8` times less memory on Linux system. Thus, such a mask based approach would be like so -

```
# Create mask
mask = np.ones(a.size, dtype=bool)
mask[::4] = 0
```

Here's the memory requirement stat -

```
In [311]: mask.itemsize
Out[311]: 1

In [312]: a.itemsize
Out[312]: 8
```

Then, we could use boolean-indexing as a view -

```
In [313]: a
Out[313]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [314]: a[mask] = 10

In [315]: a
Out[315]: array([ 0, 10, 10, 10,  4, 10, 10, 10,  8, 10])
```

---

**Approach #3 with `NumPy array strides` : Requirement as a `view`**

You can use [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py) to create such a view given the length of the input array is a multiple of `n`. If it's not a multiple, it would still work, but won't be a safe practice, as we would be going beyond the memory allocated for input array. Please note that the view thus created would be `2D`.

Thus, an implementaion to get such a view would be -

```
def skipped_view(a, n):
    s = a.strides[0]
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    return strided(a,shape=((a.size+n-1)//n,n),strides=(n*s,s))[:,1:]
```

Sample run -

```
In [50]: a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]) # Input array

In [51]: a_out = skipped_view(a, 4)

In [52]: a_out
Out[52]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])

In [53]: a_out[:] = 100 # Let's prove output is a view indeed

In [54]: a
Out[54]: array([  0, 100, 100, 100,   4, 100, 100, 100,   8, 100, 100, 100])
```

Comment: Great answer thank you @Divakar #2 looks like the best solution for me

Comment: @BenHazelwood I would agree, that works as a generic solution.

Answer (score 2):

[numpy.delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) :

```
In [18]: arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [19]: arr = np.delete(arr, np.arange(0, arr.size, 4))

In [20]: arr
Out[20]: array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9])
```

Comment: That does not look like a **view**.

Comment: I agree with @sascha in that if a more memory efficient approach exists it would be better

Answer (score 0):

The slickest answer that I found is using delete with `i` being the nth index which you want to skip:

```py
del list[i-1::i]
```

Example:

```py
In [1]: a = list([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [2]: del a[4-1::4]
In [3]: print(a)
Out[3]: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

If you also want to skip the first value, use `a[1:]`.