# NumPy: Selecting n points every m points

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a `numpy.ndarray` that's, say, 300 points in size (1 x 300 for now), and I wanted to select 10 points every 30 points, how would I do that?

In other words: I want the first 10 points, then skip 20, then grab 10 more, and then skip 10... until the end of the array.

Answer (score 5):

To select `10` elements off each block of `30` elements, we can simply reshape into `2D` and slice out the first `10` columns from each row -

```
a.reshape(-1,30)[:,:10]
```

The benefit is the output would be a view into the input and as such virtually free and without any extra memory overhead. Let's have a sample run to show and prove those -

```
In [43]: np.random.seed(0)

In [44]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(1,300))
    
In [48]: np.shares_memory(a,a.reshape(10,30)[0,:,:10])
Out[48]: True
```

If you need a flattened version, use `.ravel()` -

```
a.reshape(-1,30)[:,:10].ravel()
```

Timings -

```
In [38]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(300))

# @sacul's soln
In [39]: %%timeit
    ...: msk = [True] * 10 + [False] * 20
    ...: out = a[np.tile(msk, len(a)//len(msk))]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.6 µs per loop

# From this post
In [40]: %timeit a.reshape(-1,30)[:,:10].ravel()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 µs per loop

In [41]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(3000000))

# @sacul's soln
In [42]: %%timeit
    ...: msk = [True] * 10 + [False] * 20
    ...: out = a[np.tile(msk, len(a)//len(msk))]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.66 ms per loop

# From this post
In [43]: %timeit a.reshape(-1,30)[:,:10].ravel()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.32 ms per loop

# If you are okay with `2D` output, it is virtually free
In [44]: %timeit a.reshape(-1,30)[:,:10]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 519 ns per loop
```

---

#### Generic case with `1D` array

**A. No. of elements being multiple of block length**

For a `1D` array `a` with number of elements being a multiple of `n`, to select `m` elements off each block of `n` elements and get a `1D` array output, we would have :

```
a.reshape(-1,n)[:,:m].ravel()
```

Note that `ravel()` flattening part makes a copy there. So, if possible keep the unflattened `2D` version for memory efficiency.

Sample run -

```
In [59]: m,n = 2,5

In [60]: N = 25

In [61]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(N))

In [62]: a
Out[62]: 
array([5, 0, 3, 3, 7, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 6, 8, 8, 1, 6, 7, 7, 8, 1, 5, 8, 4,
       3, 0, 3])

# Select 2 elements off each block of 5 elements
In [63]: a.reshape(-1,n)[:,:m].ravel()
Out[63]: array([5, 0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 7, 8, 4])
```

**B. Generic no. of elements**

We would leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides), inspired by [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40929672/) to select `m` elements off each block of `n` elements -

```
def skipped_view(a, m, n):
    s = a.strides[0]
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    shp = ((a.size+n-1)//n,n)
    return strided(a,shape=shp,strides=(n*s,s), writeable=False)[:,:m]

def slice_m_everyn(a, m, n):
    a_slice2D = skipped_view(a,m,n)
    extra = min(m,len(a)-n*(len(a)//n))
    L = m*(len(a)//n) + extra
    return a_slice2D.ravel()[:L]
```

Note that `skipped_view` gets us a view into the input array and possibly into memory region not assigned to the input array, but after that we are flattening and slicing to restrict it to our desired output and that's a copy.

Sample run -

```
In [170]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(16))

In [171]: a
Out[171]: array([5, 0, 3, 3, 7, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 6, 8, 8, 1, 6, 7])

# Select 2 elements off each block of 5 elements
In [172]: slice_m_everyn(a, m=2, n=5)
Out[172]: array([5, 0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7])

In [173]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(19))

In [174]: a
Out[174]: array([5, 0, 3, 3, 7, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 6, 8, 8, 1, 6, 7, 7, 8, 1])

# Select 2 elements off each block of 5 elements
In [175]: slice_m_everyn(a, m=2, n=5)
Out[175]: array([5, 0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 7])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a mask and index by the mask, repeated until it reaches the length of your array:

```
msk = [True] * 10 + [False] * 20

arr[np.tile(msk, len(arr)//len(msk))]
```

**Minimal example:**

In an array of 30 values, select 1 element, then skip 2 elements:

```
>>> arr
array([6, 7, 2, 7, 1, 9, 1, 4, 4, 8, 6, 5, 2, 6, 3, 6, 8, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 9,
       6, 7, 2, 1, 8, 2, 2])

msk = [True] * 1 + [False] * 2

>>> arr[np.tile(msk, len(arr)//len(msk))]
array([6, 7, 1, 8, 2, 6, 6, 1, 7, 8])
```

**Explanation**:

`msk` is a boolean mask

```
>>> msk
[True, False, False]
```

You can then repeat that mask with `np.tile`, until it is the same length as your original array (*i.e.* the length of your array divided by the length of your mask):

```
>>> np.tile(msk, len(arr)//len(msk))
array([ True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Then it's a simple matter of indexing by a boolean, which `numpy` excels at

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
get = 10
skip = 20
k = [item for z in [np.arange(get) + idx for idx in np.arange(0, x.size, skip+get)] for item in z]
```

Then just slice

```
x[k]
```

---

Example:

```
x = np.arange(100)
x[k]

array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36,
       37, 38, 39, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 90, 91, 92, 93,
       94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99])
```