# Python advanced list slicing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I want to reduce the size of an image using Python

```
    import numpy as np
    from skimage import io

    img = io.imread('img.jpg')
    smallImg = img[::2, ::2]
```

gives me image which 50 percent of the original because the step size of the slice is 2. How can i make it to be let's say 90 percent of original one?

Regular python slice did not help me. It seems that i don't know how to slice a list, so it will return me for example, 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 7th etc. elements. 
Let's say i have something like:

```
    arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    arr[::2]
```

Running the code above gives me:

```
   array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
```

However, i want opposite to this result:

```
   array([2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9])
```

Comment: Do you know what the fields between ``:`` *mean*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip every nth index of numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929560/skip-every-nth-index-of-numpy-array)

Comment: `arr[np.mod(np.arange(arr.size),3)!=0]` would give you the desired output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Considering what you want to use the slicing for: for image resizing, just skipping pixels seems inappropriate. Better look for suitable interpolation methods...

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

we can easily achieve that specifiying correct index values:

```
res = arr[np.arange(len(arr)) % 3 != 0]
```

result:

```
In [59]: res
Out[59]: array([2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this slicing method

```
arr[1:3,4:6,7:9]...
```

Or you can slice the list 2 values at a time, store it in different variable, and append or extend the list together.

Answer (score -2):

To get array([2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9])
You have to alter the code to:
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
arr[1:-1:2] i forgot the step earlier

Negative indexes start form the last item
So the item indexed -1 is the last (10)
And the item indexed - 2 is before the last (9) and so on

Comment: This does not give array([2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]). It gives array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) instead.

Comment: I have edited it try it again I'm far from my pc right now